# which one is correct? (human being + lifestyle)

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct? If none of them is correct, could I ask one gives me the correct one? Is it reasonable to add " **'s**" at the end of "**being**"?

It has pernicious effect on

> 1- human being's lifestyle.
> 2- human being lifestyle.
> 3- lifestyle of human being.

Comment: All three are have issues without a context.  Why human being?  Why not just human?  Can you elaborate on your reason for putting this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them are correct.

First, it should start

> It has a pernicious effect on

or

> It has pernicious effects on

Effort 1 is close to being correct:

> on human beings' lifestyles

or

> on a human being's lifestyle

are correct though they mean different things and are both stylistic monstrosities.

Effort 2 is also close to being correct:

> on human lifestyles

or

> on a human lifestyle

are fine though they mean different things.

Effort 3 is further from being correct. You could try to correct it with

> the lifestyles of human beings

but that implies that all human beings live their lives in an identical way, which you probably do not mean to imply. It is grammatically correct to say

> the lifestyle of a human being

but that robs the statement of all force. Does anyone care whether something has a pernicious effect on the lifestyle of a serial murderer?

In short, articles have meaning in English as does the choice between singular and plural. I cannot tell you what is correct because I have no idea what you are trying to say. Are we talking about one person and that one person's specific lifestyle, or all persons and their uniform lifestyle, or all lifestyles? Is "human lifestyle" prescriptive or descriptive? The answer to the preceding questions will determine what is correct. Grammar is the servant of meaning. Frequently, when you think you have a question in grammar, what you really have is a question on what you really want to say.